# How can I override the Wi-Fi signal icon in a custom Android theme?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-theme, android-styles

I'm working on a custom Android theme and I want to override the default Wi-Fi signal icon provided by the Android SDK. I have defined a new style called "Base.Theme.WifiIssue" which extends "Theme.Material3.DayNight". Within this style, I want to replace the default Wi-Fi signal icon with a custom one called "ic_custom_wifi_signal_0".

I've tried using the following code snippet in my styles.xml file:

```
<style name="Base.Theme.WifiIssue" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight">
    <item name="android:drawable/ic_wifi_signal_0">@drawable/ic_custom_wifi_signal_0</item>
</style>
```

However, I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'android:drawable/ic_wifi_signal_0'` How can I correctly override the Wi-Fi signal icon in my custom theme? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!